# How to reduce fluctuation of a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, training, objective-functions

I've modeled an AlexNet neural network, with 50 epochs and a batch size of 64. I used a stochastic gradient descent optimizer with a learning rate of 0.01. I attached the train and validation loss and accuracy plots.

[image: Accuracy plot]

[image: Loss plot]

How can I reduce the fluctuation of the first epochs?